# Complete statistic for beta distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, estimation

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ identical independent variables that follows a beta distribution $\text{Beta}(\theta,1)$

Is $S = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ a complete statistic for $\theta$?

I have proved that the sum is not a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ but I'm having a difficult time about completeness.

If the statistic is not complete, then I need to find a function $g$ such that $E[g(S)] = 0 $ implies $g(S) = 0$ almost surely for every $\theta$. Unfortunately I have not been able to find such function.

I would really appreciate any hints or sugestions with this problem

Comment: How did you prove $S$ is not sufficient?

Comment: I prove that a minimal sufficient statistic is the sum of logarithms of X. A minimal sufficient statistic is a function of every other sufficient statistic. IF S was a sufficient statistic then there exist a function F such that F(S) = sum of logarithm of X, but that is not possible